# how to call popup function from jsp to dust.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsp, dust.js

i have done with popup function but do not know how to call it in dust template from jsp .

```
<a id="disclaimer" onClick="openPopup()">Disclaimer</a>
<script>
    function openPopup() {
        $("#dialog").dialog({
            model : true,
            autoOpen : false,
            draggable : false,
            title : "Disclaimer",
            width : 886,
            height : 196
        });
        $("#dialog").dialog('open');

    }
</script>
```

please help me out to resolve it 
any answer would highly appreciated.

Comment: Well, you cannot "call" Javascript code from JSP. The key is to realize, **where** and **when** which code is executed - JSP on the server, when the page is requested and rendered (i.e. **before** the response is sent to the browser), and Javascript in the browser, **after** the browser receives the **already generated** response.

Comment: so any alternative for that but i want to use dust in this case ?

Comment: What is your use case? When do you need to open that pop-up?

Comment: its like if(condtion==true){open popup}else do not show the popup link on the footer.

Comment: The [<c:if>](https://beginnersbook.com/2013/11/jstl-cif-core-tag/) JSTL tag is not enough? In combination with e.g. [$(document).ready()](https://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/) from jQuery?

Comment: yeah right how can i miss that got it. Thank you @JozefChocholacek